# Which Windows Azure technology to use?

Tags: c#, web-services, architecture, azure

I googled for hours and read a lot of stuff, but I just seem to be too dumb to find the correct answer.

I want to create an azure web Service. And I am not sure which technology from azure I should use...

Before I am starting to read deeply into the topic, I want to be sure, that I am reading into the right one...

I want to create an application that should be able to be used by a lot of customers. (so its important that its very easy that 100 and also 1.000.000 users can communicate with the service. azure is scalable easily, so thats why I decided to use azure)

Each customer can buy a subscription and is then able to connect to the service with its username and id.

Each customer can connect to the service with different clients (e.g. browser, windows-client, iOS, android, ....)

What I already know is how the data layer (data access components connect to azureSql, ...) and the business layer will work. (business layers application facade is there in C#.net and will be able to run in an azure app)

What also doesnt matter is the client side.

I just have to figure out, the communication between the business facade and all the external systems, that will use them (i.e. clients)

So: What shall I use as Technology for the Services Layer? Which message types,...

Important is, if one of the many endusers is communicating through two different clients (with the same username and password) with the service, and the client lets say is changing something through the business layer, so that data that will be presented on each client has to be changed, the other client has to receive that change pretty instantly. (simultaneously: one change from one client, will affect all the other clients from one users that are connected at that moment) if they are not connected, they will get the Change at the next Login...

What I mean by that is, it just should not matter at all which client the customer is using (or if more than one, it shouldnt matter as well)

Because every client is offering the same functionality anyhow: there is a login, and after that the user will se some data and can process that data..

It would be perfect, if someone who is experienced in messaging and communication can help me out, by telling me the right way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very difficult to answer concisely.

However, here are a few pointers to get you started:

It is entirely possible to build services hosted in Azure that can handle many millions of users if you wish. This is why the Halo4 team built all of their services atop Azure!

Since you want your users to be able to access your service from browsers and from apps running on different platforms, you're going to want to built your service in three main parts:

1. Services exposing an HTTP-based API accessible by anything that can talk XML/JSON over HTTP(S), including ...
2. An HTML5 website to allow your users to access your system via web browsers
3. [Optional] Mobile apps providing a platform-specific experience of your system.

You are most likely going to need to build and expose your API layer as one or more [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) service(s) that accept HTTP GET/POST/PUT/DELETE messages containing JSON/XML data.

If you plan on using Microsoft's .NET stack to build this API layer, I strongly encourage you to start reading-up on [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Your website, of course, can be built using ASP.NET. I prefer building websites using [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) because I prefer the clean separation of concerns offered by the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) approach. Having said that, there's nothing to stop you from building your site using [ASP.NET Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) if you prefer.

If you want to build services that are particularly dynamic, you could also employ technologies like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to build services that can dynamically broadcast notifications of data changes to multiple browser pages, multiple browsers and multiple apps running on multiple devices by multiple people!

Of course, building systems that can scale to handle many thousands of concurrent users requires careful thought, planning and experimentation. If you've not done this before, you're going to have to do a lot of reading and a lot of experimentation, but in doing so, you'll have a lot of fun too :)

Luckily, Azure offers several important technologies to make it easier to build such cloud-scale systems including caching, queuing, mobile notifications, relational database, table/queue/blob storage, federated authentication, PAAS roles, IAAS virtual machine instances, CDN, etc.

I honestly can't think of many systems that you CAN'T build atop Azure's powerful infrastructure.

I would, however, suggest starting small. Focus on building one core piece of your system first. Learn how it works, how to deploy it, how to monitor it, how to measure it's performance and reliability, how to patch and update it. Then bite off another chunk and repeat.

Oh ... and if you're planning on using PAAS/IAAS roles/VM's, be sure to shut them down and delete them when you're NOT developing/testing because you'll get billed for every hour they run, whether or not you're using them or have anything deployed to those instances!

As for the various applications you want to build to access your services, you have MANY choices to make. One thing to consider that may help simplify your choices is [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page). Mono is an open-source implementation of .NET that runs on practically every platform you're likely to come across - Linux, Android, iOS, OSX, Windows Phone, Windows desktop, Windows 8, Play Station, XBox, etc. By using Mono, and carefully architecting your apps, you'll be able to re-use a great deal of your code across multiple apps targeting multiple platforms.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything specific to Azure here.

I would recommend [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), which is a very good library in .Net for "near real-time messaging". It is easy to setup in .Net environment ([for example for a Web app with Asp.Net](http://www.asp.net/signalr)), in Azure or not.

I heard about some signalR clients for Android and IOs, but you should look if they are mature and feed your needs.